# Yii - How can I get a dropdownlist based on the value of first dropdownlist

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to Yii framework.
I have two dropdownlists with their values hardcoded in properties file. The dropdownlists are created using the below code:

```
<?php
$this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'min',
    'data' => Yii::app()->params['min_values'],
    'options' => array(
        'allowText' => false,
     ),
     'htmlOptions' => array('placeholder' => 'Min', 'style'=>'width:70px'),
));
?>
```

So now I want to get the hardcoded values in second dropdownlist based on first.

If first dropdownlist has hardcoded values[1,2,3,4] and second dropdownlist has hardcoded values [1,2,3,4]. Suppose I select 2 in first dropdownlist, the second dropdownlist should have values 3 and 4(greater than value selected in first). How can I do this?

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about yii. You sholud use javascript for things like that.

For start check this:

```
<select id='first'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
</select>

<select id='second'>
</select>

<script>
$('#first').on('change', function(e){
    var $options =  $(this).find('option');
    $('#second').html('');
    $.each($options, function(i, element){
        if($(element).attr('value')>$('#first').val()){
            $('#second').append($(element).clone());
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kj5TK/

Comment: I want to know how to use this in Yii

Comment: As I'm not familiar with Javascript, can you tell me how can I use for the above code

Comment: Just put the script into the view. Or even beter use the CClientScript.

Comment: In the script replace the id for the id that is generated in your html.

Comment: Sorry, does ext.jui.combobox give id

Comment: Check the generated code (view source in the browser). And also you can override the id in htmlOptions too.

Comment: And afcourse you can modify the script to use classes instead of ids.

Comment: I got the id but what about value and options. My hard code is simply given in an array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40812/discussion-between-user2770039-and-harryfink)